# GemFire Client Cache role

Tags: client-server, gemfire

I am new to GemFire and I am unable to figure out or find an answer to this question.

Please help!

In GemFire Client server topology does client cache only manage the connection pool? Or does it also maintains and serves its own cached data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ClientCache` manages the connection pool, it also manages the subscription connections that the client has open with the server (for CQ and register interest).
When you create the client side regions, you can configure them to optionally cache the data it received from the server.

```
Region r = this.clientCache.
        createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY)
        .create("customer");
```

Creating a PROXY region *will not* cache the data on the client. Creating a CACHING_PROXY region *will* cache the data locally.

```
Region r = this.cache.
        createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY)
        .create("customer");
```

If you want to cache data on the client, you should consider using `CACHING_PROXY_HEAP_LRU` or `CACHING_PROXY_OVERFLOW` to ensure that your client does not run out of memory.

If other clients are capable of updating the data that you cached locally, then you can [Register Interest](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/events/configure_client_server_event_messaging.html) with the server so that all the changes are pushed to your client.

Comment: Thanks, this helped!